# Ignore Repeated content in a String in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-requests

I am looking for support to Ignore repeated content in a string.

a= "Item 1.01    Entry the party thereto Item 2.02 Exit Item 4.02 Please go from Item 1.01 Item 5.06 lets have some party "

I want Output as Item 1.01, Item 2.02, Item 4.02, Item 5.06, i have used following code

```
b=re.split('Item',a)
code=[]
for i in range(0,len(b[1:])):
  code.append('Item' + " "+ b[1:][i][1:5])
code
```

I am getting Ouput as ['Item 1.01', 'Item 2.02', 'Item 4.02', 'Item 1.01','Item 5.06'] while i dont need repeated element which is 'Item 1.01'. Desired output

['Item 1.01', 'Item 2.02', 'Item 4.02','Item 5.06']

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import re

a = "Item 1.01 Entry the party thereto Item 2.02 Exit Item 4.02 Please go from Item 1.01 Item 5.06 lets have some party"

code = []
for i in re.findall(r"Item \d+(?:\.\d+)?", a):
    if not i in code:
        code.append(i)

print(code)  # ['Item 1.01', 'Item 2.02', 'Item 4.02', 'Item 5.06']
```